# How to bind pikaday value with laravel livewire property

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-livewire, alpine.js, pikaday

I am pretty new to laravel livewire and I've been trying to add a pikaday js onto my project but unfortunately, I am unable to bind the selected date into livewire's public property.

main file (the $datebox2 is a public property inside the livewire component but it is always empty regardless of the date):

```html
<div class="">
        <input x-text="$wire.set('datebox2', picker)" type="text" id="datepicker">
        @include('components._ndatetime-picker')
   </div>
```

components._ndatetime-picker.blade.php file

```html
<div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pikaday/css/pikaday.css">

    <script src="pikaday.js"></script>
    <script>
        var picker = new Pikaday({ 
            field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
            onSelect: date => {
                var year = date.getFullYear(),
                month = date.getMonth() + 1,
                day = date.getDate(),
                formattedDate = [
                    year,
                    month < 10 ? '0' + month : month,
                    day < 10 ? '0' + day : day
                ].join('-')
                document.getElementById('datepicker').value = formattedDate
            }
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `wire:model` on your input? https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#data-binding